# v0.8 explicit uint->int conversion no longer permitted; best new approach?

Tags: solidity

v0.7.x of `solc` permitted easy conversion of `uint256` to `int64` where it was well-known that the incoming `uint256` was well within the range of `int64`.  This is a popular and useful way to prep material for eventual manipulation in signed 64bit integer environments (e.g. Java 'long'):

```
int64 x = int64(some_uint256);
```

This has been removed in v0.8.x and yields:

```
Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "int64".
```

What is the new best practice for safely/easily "cast-truncating" `uint256` variables to smaller signed integers in v.0.8x?

Answer (score 6):

You can cast it to an `uint64` first, and then to the `int64`.

```
int64 x = int64(uint64(some_uint256));
```

Comment: This also works in reverse. I had a case from int16 to uint256 and this worked:
`uint256 x = uint256(uint16(someInt16));`  
So first do `uint` vs `int` conversion, and only then convert to right number of bits.